# Populating #options, #header for tableselect in ajax callback function

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

[image]
What I am trying to do is display a table with checkboxes on the press of a button by ajax. The table should be initially hidden and get populated on the fly by a function call. 
If initially I load $options1 with some dummy values , then after ajax call it throws in an error saying-

> Notice: Undefined index: red in theme_tableselect() (line 3285 of
>   D:\wamp\www\drupal7\includes\form.inc).

where 'red' is the index of a dummy row value and #options don't get populated with the new values. What is the way to get this working ?

Here is the code for the form-

```
$form['mltag_new']['tag'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t("Suggest Tags"),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'mltag_suggest_tags_ajax',
            'wrapper' => 'mltag_suggest_tags_table_div',
            'effect' => 'slide',
            ),
    );




 $options1 = array();                      //initial dummy values
    $options1['red']['tag'] = "A red row";
    $options1['red']['chi'] = "A red row";


 $form['mltag_new']['myselector'] = array (
        '#type' => 'tableselect',
        '#title' => 'My Selector',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options1,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="mltag_suggest_tags_table_div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',        
    );

    return $form;
```

and the Ajax callback looks something like this-

```
function mltag_suggest_tags_ajax($form, $form_state) {
          //$content has some content
          //pass the content to a function 
          include_once 'includes/content_tag.inc';
          $tags = mltag_content_tag($content, variable_get('algo_type'), 20);

          if (empty($tags)) {
            $output .= t('Content is insufficient to generate Tags using this algorithm. <br>Please choose other algorithm from Settings Page.');
            $form['mltag_new']['sample_text']['#markup'] = $output;
            return $form['mltag_new']['sample_text'];
          }
          else {
            $algo = variable_get('algo_type');
            if ($algo == 1) {
              $header = array(
                  'tag' => t('Tag'),
                  'frequency' => t('Frequency'), 
                  );

              $options = array();      
              foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
                $options[$key] = array(
                    'tag' => $key,
                    'frequency' => $value,
                    );
              }    
            }

            elseif ($algo == 2) {
              $header = array(
                  'tag' => t('Tag'),
                  'chi' => t('Chi Square Value'), 
                  );

              $options = array();

              foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
                $options[$key] = array(
                    'tag' => $key,
                    'chi' => $value,
                ); 
              } 

            }

          $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['#header'] = $header; 
          $form['mltag_new']['myselector']['#options'] = $options;
          return $form['mltag_new']['myselector'];
          }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I replied to your post on Drupal.org about how I'm working on a somewhat similar problem. Try adding

```
$form['mltag_new']['myselector'] =
    form_process_tableselect($form['mltag_new']['myselector']);
```

just before your return. Hopefully that helps you more than it did me. Beware that the #options just get rendered when the block reloads from the ajax, but the original $form object doesn't seem to be aware.

Comment: I should add that I don't know if this has anything to do with that error you're getting. I had some somewhat similar code that wasn't getting an error, but also wasn't updating the table at all. So, that is what I'm suggesting this code might address for you.

Comment: I figured out my problem, and it seems that making these updates in the callback function was not the proper approach, although it may still work for you. What worked for me was placing the logic to build the options list in the process function that was in turn being called every time the ajax callback reloaded that block. Then all the ajax function was doing was just reloading that element.

Comment: hey thanks a lot ! that seems to have done the trick.. I was still getting the red-index error but I deleted the initial dummy $options1 that I was passing and it worked along with your answer.

Comment: any idea how can I alter the column widths of the tables ? they are too wide for my purpose. 
and now I am returning 2 tables from my call back function. 
what is the proper approach you are talking about ? can you please post a short snippet of using the callback function the correct way ?

Comment: my $form_state['values']['mltag_new']['myselector'] is also returning an empty array now on form submit. That is the selected row are not getting returned by $form_state. any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a few years later, but I found this while searching for my own solution:

The tableselect module creates checkboxes in the $ form that have to be removed. in the example above, they would be in `$form['mltag_new']['myselector']` with keys equal to the original `$option1` in your original code. If you unset those, then **call**

```
 $form['mltag_new']['myselector'] = form_process_tableselect($form['mltag_new']['myselector']);
```

before your return, it will eliminate the dummy rows.